# How do I write import statements within a monorepo using turborepo?

Tags: monorepo, turborepo

I'm developing a web app using turborepo in a monorepo setup. I'm not sure how I write import statements when importing things from the same packages.

For example, if I have following directory:

```
.
└── packages/
    └── ui/
        ├── Button/
        │   └── button.tsx
        └── Dialog/
            └── dialog.tsx
```

Suppose you want to import a Button from within a Dialog.

- By default, I can use relative path like `import { Button } from "../Button"`.
- Some repositories use tsconfig to import like `import { Button } from "@ui/Button"`
- When not using monorepo, I often see `import { Button } from "@/Button"`

I'm not very familiar with monorepos, and I'm not sure if using path aliases is a common practice or not.
Can anyone give me some advice on the way to write import statements in a monorepo?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We are using relative paths for a similar case in our production Turborepo app. In the first one you're passing the exact path to the Button component from the Dialog component by `../Button`. There is nothing wrong in that.

And in the second and third options, you added path aliases where `@ui` or `@` are basically **path aliases**, where you're saying `@ui` = `my/root/path`.

We generally use aliases to keep import statements looking cleaner. Because if you have a multi-level deep folder structure. It can be ugly and confusing to have import paths like `../../../../Button`. So it will be better to have a path alias in this case.

And you can create as many aliases as you want. Not just `@ui/` or `@/`